# Supabase Storage with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, supabase

I am currently implementing Supabase storage into my SwiftUI project and Im having issues with listing all available buckets.

I have two public buckets. That should be visible by anyone. I have tried with Supabase and SupabaseStorage with no luck.

I have tried with and without Authorization in the header and I also tried to upload using CURL with no luck.

```
let storage = SupabaseStorageClient(url: "https://xxx.supabase.co", headers: [
    "apikey" : "anon",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {JWT Secret}"
])

let client = SupabaseClient(supabaseURL: URL(string: "https://xxx.supabase.co")!, supabaseKey: "anon")

func uploadProfilePhoto(for user: AppUser, photoData: Data) async throws {
    let file = File(name: "profile_photo", data: photoData, fileName: "profile_photo.jpg", contentType: "jpg")
    let bucketsOne = try await storage.listBuckets()
    let bucketsTwo = try await client.storage.listBuckets()
}
```

Comment: This isn’t related to SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

Can your try instantiating the storage client as shown here: https://github.com/supabase-community/storage-swift#instantiating-the-client

```swift
import Supabase
import SupabaseStorage

lazy var supabaseClient: SupabaseClient = {
    return SupabaseClient(supabaseURL: supabaseUrl, supabaseKey: anonKey)
}()

lazy var supabaseStorageClient: SupabaseStorageClient = {
    return supabaseClient.storage
}()
```